# "Unable to locate GDB" in Trigger Toolkit

Tags: iphone, trigger.io

I'm attempting to run an iPhone app in the Trigger Toolkit, but I keep getting "Unable to locate GDB" in the console, several seconds after "Connecting to remote debug server" . I've updated xcode, installed gdb separately through homebrew, and am able to run it (gdb) through the command line.

Thanks in advance for any relevant advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using a pre-v2.0.1 platform version here, and that you've updated to Xcode 5?

I was able to reproduce this error in that configuration. Xcode 5 [doesn't support GDB](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html), which we were previously using to communicate with the app running on your device.

If updating to use newer platform versions isn't an option for you, you could use an older installation of Xcode (you can have several versions installed as siblings), and use `xcode-select` to point us at it, e.g.:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode4.6/Xcode.app
```